# c function turns my factor data into numbers in barplot?

Tags: r, function, concatenation, bar-chart

I am facing a problem with a barplot that I am trying to do.

The bar chart basically shows the frequency of words that presidents of the USA have said during their inauguration speech. When I am doing the plot for 1 president is fine. However when I try to add more presidents, all the "words" in the plot change to numbers. Even though the frequency bars of the new president are being added correctly, all the words of the plot change to numbers. My aim is to have 11 presidents, but I need to know how to add them right.

Below you can see both pieces of code that I have so far. I am not sure whether the concatenate function is the most appropriate one for my case either. Any suggestions welcome as I am a beginner in R. The image I attached shows the bar charts for both pieces of code so far. The second one is the one I am trying to fix. Thank you!

```
    barplot(dfTrump[1:3,]$freq, las = 1, names.arg = (dfTrump[1:3,]$word),
    col ="red", main ="Most Frequent Words of Donald Trump\nDuring his Inauguration Speech ",
    ylab = "Frequency of Words",xlab = "Words")


    barplot(c(dfTrump[1:3,]$freq,dfObama[1:3,]$freq), las = 1, names.arg = c(dfTrump[1:3,]$word, dfObama[1:3,]$word),
    col ="red", main ="Most Frequent Words of Trump and Obama\nDuring his Inauguration Speech ",
    ylab = "Frequency of Words", xlab = "Words")
```

Click here https://ibb.co/jNUzK6 to see the barcharts.

Comment: You can't just combine 2 different factors. Convert to character, combine, refactor. If you need more help than that, please make a reproducible example by sharing a little bit of data.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
dfTot <- merge(dfObama[1:3,], dfTrump[1:3,], all = TRUE)
barplot(dfTot$freq, las = 1, names.arg = (dfTot$word),
    col ="red", main ="Most Frequent Words of Trump and Obama\nDuring his 
Inauguration Speech ",
    ylab = "Frequency of Words", xlab = "Words")
```

But what do you want to do if the same word appear ? Two bars for the same word ? colors according to speaker ?

Comment: Thank you MrSmithGoesToWashington. That's lovely! Yeah, I don't mind if the same word appears over and over again, but I would like to differentiate the words according to the speakers. Is there a way we could do different colours of the words according to the speaker?